# Как заставить queue:work работать на хостинге Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, веб-программирование

Сразу предупреждаю, я знаю, что на эту тему есть много тем. Однако большинство этих тем относятся к 2014 и 2015 годам, когда еще существовал тег --daemon. Есть также некоторые темы 2017 года, которые не полностью объясняют, как сделать все правильно.

Я в контролере отправляю job (драйвер database и таблица jobs (по умолчанию которая))

```
SendMail::dispatch($supervisorEmail,$project,$candidate);
```

Вот сам мой SendMail job

```html
class SendMail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $supervisorEmail;
    public $project;
    public $candidate;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($supervisorEmail,$project,$candidate)
    {
        $this->supervisorEmail = $supervisorEmail;
        $this->project = $project;
        $this->candidate = $candidate;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Mail::to($this->supervisorEmail)->send(new CandidateOrderMail($this->project,$this->candidate));
    }
}
```

У меня есть только SSH-консоль в пользовании. Заказчик на своем сервере мне выделил отдельную папку (не root-права), поэтому я не могу Supervisord поставить (ему по барабану, как это реализуется, он не дает мне root-права  ツ)

Обшарив весь русо-англоязычный интернет, я нашел лишь два более менее понятных и вроде рабочих решений (не пробовал пока еще). Да, есть еще некоторые темы 2017 года в англ. интернете, где поднимался этот вопрос, однако там используется --daemon, который как бы устарел еще в 2015 году. Ребята, выручайте, одним словом.

Два метода этих:

1. /usr/local/bin/php /home/electro/public_html/artisan queue:work( this is writing to the command line, right)?
2. nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon &

Что мне использовать из этого? Я просто думаю, если запущу, то откатить назад на сервере будет еще та головная боль.

Желательно, чтобы еще все работало, если сервер перезапустится (или там какая-то ошибка случится)

Comment: @TotalPusher Я вас приглашу в тему,  как опытный разработчик, думаю вы знаете решение данной проблемы

Comment: 1. Что бы проблем с тем как откатить назад не было, тестируйте локально, создайте тоже окружение. 2. Используйте крон, поставте туда задачу просто и все, он то обычно везде есть

Comment: @EvgeniiIzhboldin По поводу крона я не знаю, как его достать в ограниченного timeweb хостинга (в виде приложения). Мне лишь дали (небольшая организация) папку и SSH-консоль. Да, через ssh-консоль на англоязычном форуме вызывали cron --> * * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/username/project/artisan schedule:run > /dev/null 2>&1 . Однако не знаю, зачем мне cron в данном случае, так как мне лишь же нужно запустить queue:work в фоновом режиме.. Можешь немного прояснить, я тут запутался что мне надо, так как уже все, что можно прочитал на англ ресурсе, а понять ничего не могу.

Comment: тут стоит понять что именно у Вас на тайвебе, если это именно просто веб-хоситнг, скорее всего у Вас просто не будет прав там что-то запустить в фоне, веб хостинги как правило ориентированы на запуск только тех услуг, которые там есть, т.е. например строго php  скрипты и ничего более Вы не запустите, либо запустите, но потом возникнут вопросы от хостера, т.к. запуск произвольных демонов и "фоновых задач" - это уже удел VPS. И потому как правило вариантов запустить что-то в фоне на веб-хостинге кроме крона особо и нет. Если же у Вас именно VPS, то тут вопросов нет, можете и в фоне запустить

Comment: И если это веб хостинг таймвеба, то вроде крон панель у них там есть в виде веб раздела

Comment: @EvgeniiIzhboldin Спасибо за ответ, гляну! https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1205914/Как-построить-поисковый-запрос-на-пересечение-в-pivot-таблице-laravel --> если будет время, сможешь заглянуть на этот мой вопрос, тут я не могу поисковое условие правильно построить

Answer (score 0):

> Желательно, чтобы еще все работало, если сервер перезапустится (или там какая-то ошибка случится)

К сожалению, если нет менеджеров процессов (тот же супервизор), то очередь не надо делать.

Я запускал на shared хостинге очередь при помощи крона, своего `.pid` файла очереди и `--once` параметра очереди, но такая реализация - это костыль, который ломается при перезапуске сервака (к счастью на shared хостинге серваки не часто перезагружают).

Если интересно, можешь спросить в личку