# Как построить поисковый запрос на пересечение в pivot-таблице Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, веб-программирование

У меня есть 3 таблицы

Книги --> id, название книги

Теги --> id, название тега

книга_тег --> id_книги, id_тега

Книга может иметь много тегов и наоборот тег может иметь много книг (многие-ко-многим) связь. Я хочу организовать поиск таким образом, чтобы выдавались книги только те, что указаны в поиске. Например, в поиске я ищу книги с тегами: комедия и боевик. И поисковый запрос мне выдавал толкьо лишь книги с этими тегами. Чтобы не выдавались книги, которые имеют теги: комедия, боевик и еще какие-то теги.

Я пытался организовать это с помощью WhereIn, однако ничего не получилось, так как как раз в поисковый запрос включаются книги, которые кроме тех поисковых тегов имеют еще дополнительные. Например, я ищу книги с тегами: детектив, комедия, а в поисковый ответ включаются еще книги, которые имеют теги: детектив,комедия,триллер,боевик. То есть, включатся книги, которые кроме поисковых еще имеют дополнительные, что мне не нужно.
Вот, что я пытался сделать (однако неудачно, так как дополнительные книги включаются)

```
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
  if ($request->has($tag->tag))
     $filteredTags[] = $tag->id;
}
if ($filteredTags != null) {
  $booksQuery->whereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($filteredTags) {
      $q->whereIn('id',$filteredTags);
  });
}
```

Comment: Можно дополнительно сверять количество тегов в поиске и количество тегов у конкретной книги

Comment: `Group by` + `having`

Comment: @u_mulder Можете написать хотя бы SQL запрос, а я его уже потом переводу в Laravel-конструкцию?

Answer (score 1):

Помимо способа в комментарии, можно сделать достаточно интересным способом и пойти от обратного. Т.е.

**1.** ищем теги НЕ включающие теги для поиска.

```
$filteredTags= Tags::whereNotIn('id', $tags_id)->get()->pluck('id'); 
//где $tags_id = [1, 2, 3, ...] те которые пришли в request!
//вывод: [4, 5, 6]
```

**2.** Далее просто замените Ваш `whereIn` в теле функции `whereHas` на `whereNotIn` и Вы получите только те книги где есть только интересующие Вас теги

```
$booksQuery->whereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($filteredTags) {
    $q->whereNotIn('id',$filteredTags);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению с laravel не работал. Вариантов как мне видится 2.

1. Создать запрос, который сначала находит все книги, у которых всего 2 тега, а потом уже находит те, у которых есть нужные теги. Пример привел ниже. Если по простому: третий `INNER JOIN` находит книги, у которых 2 тега, а дальше уже основной запрос, который фильтрует по нужным тегам

   ```
    SELECT DISTINCT book.idbook, book.name FROM book
    INNER JOIN book_tag ON book.idbook = book_tag.id_book
    INNER JOIN tag ON book_tag.id_tag = tag.idtag AND (tag.name = "t1" OR tag.name = "t2")
    INNER JOIN (SELECT book.idbook, book.name FROM book
                INNER JOIN book_tag ON book.idbook = book_tag.id_book
                GROUP BY book.idbook
                HAVING count(book_tag.id_book) = 2) as Tbl ON Tbl.idbook = book.idbook;
   ```
2. Делать выборку по нужным тегам простым запросом, и потом уже с помощью PHP удалять книги, у коготорых есть ненужные теги.